# How to factorize a string to check its belonging to language that is generated from alphabet?

Tags: tokenize, automata-theory

Let S= {a, bb, bab, abaab} is an alphabet. and kleene closure will be S* will all possible combinations.

Is string abaabbabbaab exists in S*?

what is the method to factorize to check whether it is in S* or not?
I have done it, by the following ways, 
Possible factorization:

1. (abaab)(bab)(b)(a)(a)(b)
2. (abaab)(bab)(b)(aa)(b)
3. (abaab)(bab)(ba)(ab)
4. (abaab)(bab)(baa)(b)
5. (abaab)(bab)(b)(aab)

we can see that (abaab)(bab) is matching , but later part is not matching will combinations in S*. I have factorized the later part in many ways, but still its not matching. 
I want to ask that,

- is it correct?
- Is this correct way to factorize(tokenize) the string?
- are all factorization pairs are correct?
- is this correct method to check a string whether it is belong to a
  language or not?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your factoriztions contain $(b)$, which is not in $S$. So they are not correct.

I think your method is exhaustive trial and error. If you do that correctly, it is a correct way to find a factorization. For checking membership of a language, it works if the language is given in the form of the Kleene closure of a finite language.

Comment: Is string abaabbabbaab exists in S*?  its mean, 
i have factored this string, not alphabet. You can see this string and then factors that i have made.

Comment: The string $abaabbabbaab$ is not in $S^*$. All your factorizations inlcude factors that are not from $S$. Just look at the right end of the string. None of the five strings from $S$ is a suffix of the string; thus it is clear that it cannot be factorized.